# Embed route value parameter in MVC Url Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am struggling with the MVC syntax for setting up the image src with the below code. I use Webform view engine and following the syntax

```
<img src="<%: Url.Action("LoadPhoto", "EmployeeProfile", 
                                     new { empno = "<%: ViewBag.EmpNo%>"}) %>" />
```

getting this error `Newline in constant`

How to embed this ViewBag value as a route parameter for Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already in code, the following should work:

```
<img src="<%: Url.Action("LoadPhoto", "EmployeeProfile",
                         new { empno = ViewBag.EmpNo }) %>" />
```

(I'm reasonably sure the newline mentioned in the error isn't the one between `"EmployeeProfile",` and `new { ... }`.)

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` is not supported by MVC 2. You should use `ViewData` instead like this:

```
<img src="<%: Url.Action("LoadPhoto", "EmployeeProfile",
                         new { empno = ViewData["EmpNo"] }) %>" />
```